# How to write .csv from another .csv in Bash or Ksh

Tags: matlab, csv, export-to-csv, ksh

I have a lot of output's from my matlab in .csv. I would like to put them together in one output.csv file.

So my idea was use my .csv created by Matlab as variables for my output.csv global.

```
#!/bin/ksh -p
# Reading results from results.csv

echo Study name?
read NAME
cd PROJECTS/04_${NAME}
sed -i 's/\r//g' Results.csv
while IFS=";" read -r R1 R2 R3
do
echo $R1
echo $R2
echo $R3

while IFS=";" write -r var1 var2 var3 var4
do
var1=$NAME
var2=$R1
var3=$R2
var4=$R3
done > >(tail -n +2 /PROJECTS/teste_output.csv)

done < <(tail /PROJECTS/04_${NAME}/Results.csv)
```

Each results.csv are in this format :

```
2.1680114865303;0;-0.00516967741714325
```

Using my code for one specific file i get :

```
2.1680114865303
0
-0.00516967741714325
```

What's mean it's doing the first part but its not writing in my output.csv.

So i would like to know how to write in this case. Is it possible to read more than 1 .csv at the same time?

In my dreams i would like to have code with one more while to read a list of files, get results.csv and write into output.csv:

```
#!/bin/ksh -p
# Reading results from results.csv

while IFS=";" read -r NAME c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11
do
cd PROJECTS/04_${NAME}
sed -i 's/\r//g' Results.csv
while IFS=";" read -r R1 R2 R3
do
echo $R1
echo $R2
echo $R3

while IFS=";" write -r var1 var2 var3 var4
do
var1=$NAME
var2=$R1
var3=$R2
var4=$R3

done > >(tail -n +2 /PROJECTS/teste_output.csv)

done < <(tail /PROJECTS/04_${NAME}/Results.csv)

done < <(tail -n +2 /PROJECTS/input.csv)
```

So i read a list of files in my input.csv , i get NAME , get results from this NAME and put in my global output.csv.

From now, my code it's able to read the list, read the results from matlab (results.csv) but it's not writing in my output.csv. If its easier, i could make 2 or 3 bash scripts for do it step by step.

I already tried with bash and ksh but none of them worked.

Thanks for you help in advance :)

Comment: @oguzismail but i just want do assignements and put it inside my output. I dont need to see it.

Comment: I assume that all contributing CSV have the identical header and identical field separator, because otherwise it is pointless to glue them together. In this case, just catenate them together, dropping the header line except in the first one.

Comment: Also, please sanitize your tags: Even if you experimented for a solution using various shell, make up your mind whether you want a solution in bash or rather in ksh.

Comment: If it makes sense to append all input files sequentially, you can simply chain your inputs, e.g. `done < <(tail /PROJECTS/04_${NAME}/Results.csv; tail -n +2 /PROJECTS/input.csv)`

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?
(Making a few guesses...)

```
read -p "Study name? " name
in=PROJECTS/04_"${name}"/Results.csv
out=/PROJECTS/teste_output.csv
sed -i 's/\r//g' "$in"
printf "Study," > "$out"
head -1 "in" >> "$out"
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do echo "$name;$line"
done < <(tail -n +2 "$in") >> "$out"
```

I switched your input and output - sorry if that's not what you meant.
This doesn't parse the fields, just leaves the separataors in place and prepends the study name, and does it all in one loop.

Again, apologies if I misread your intent.